# Displaying the child elements of a particular node in a boot of a bootstrap tree using DJango

Tags: django

i am developing a webpage in DJANGO which contains a bootstrap tree view. Now if i click o a particular node i need to display the children in a bootstrap list.
Here is my view

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = dict()
    organization = Organization.objects.all()
    orglocations = Orglocations.objects.all()
    locationprocessarea = Locationprocessarea.objects.all()
    processareaasset = Processareaasset.objects.all()
    processtaglink = Processareaassettaglink.objects.all()
    context["TreeStructure"] = [
        {
            'text': organizations.name,
            'nodes': [
                {
                    'text': orglocationss.name,
                    'nodes': [
                        {
                            'text': processarea.name,
                            'nodes': [
                                {
                                    'text': processasset.name,
                                    'nodes':[{
                                        'text':processareafilter.name,
                                        'nodes':[{
                                            'text':taglink.name
                                        }for taglink in processtaglink.filter(areaassetid=processareafilter.id)]
                                    }for processareafilter in processareaasset.filter(parentassetid=processasset.id)]
                                } for processasset in processareaasset.filter(processareaid=processarea.id).filter(parentassetid__isnull=True)]
                        } for processarea in locationprocessarea.filter(locationid=orglocationss.id)]
                } for orglocationss in orglocations.filter(organizationid_id=organizations.id)]
        } for organizations in organization.filter(id=1)]
    return {

        "tree_view": context
    }
```

thanks in advance`enter code here`

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Hi,, thanks for your reply..I have to display the details of a particular node in a bootstrap list.

Comment: following is my template

Comment: sorry not able to upload my template in the comment